# SharePoint 2007 web parts integration with Project Server 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, integration, project-server-2007

To my knowledge, web parts have the ability to display portions of other Web pages.

Is it possible to integrate SharePoint 07 with Project Server 07 and display portions of a Web page from the Project Server via a web part that's on a SharePoint site. If it's possible, how difficult is it to do?

I found these pages ([Integration with Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454209%28office.12%29.aspx), and [SharePoint Integration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.insidesharepoint.aspx#id0080012)) explaining a bit about the integration but I'm no SharePoint expert, I'm actually new to SharePoint, so much of what is mentioned there doesn't help me much.

Comment: Just for context: we're using MOSS 2003 at the moment and we're busy migrating to a MOSS 2007 environment (I believe the Enterprise edition which Mike mentioned below). I'm a co-op student that's been hired mainly to help with this migration project - I came in with little knowledge of these MS platforms but I've been learning a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already be aware that Project Server actually *is* SharePoint, with additional components. A Project Web Access (PWA) portal is a SharePoint site collection that is aware of both the SharePoint content database and the four Project Server databases, and contains a boatload of web parts and pages that present Project data and manage processes within the SharePoint site collection

The simplest out-of-the-box web part for showing pages within a SharePoint page is the Page Viewer Web Part. Under the hood, it drops an IFrame on the page to give the effect of looking at a page within a page.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Project Server is actually SharePoint, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Project Server but I am familiar with SharePoint. Web Parts in SharePoint can contain any arbitrary code and are more or less identical to regular ASP.NET web parts - in fact SharePoint web parts inherit from ASP.NET web parts.

From the second article you mentioned, it looks like Project Server contains its own set of SharePoint web parts, so you are likely to get better integration with SharePoint using these than simply by displaying a web page inside another one (sounds to me more like an IFRAME).

As a quick SharePoint overview, there are 3 versions of SPT 2007 - Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, which ships alongside Windows Server 2003; Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) 2007 Standard, which adds portal, content management and enterprise search features; and MOSS 2007 Enterprise, which adds other tools for line-of-business app integration, including the Business Data Catalog (BDC). The BDC is meant to be an easy way of getting line-of-business data into SharePoint. It uses an XML definition file but don't try cutting one by hand!

However, SharePoint 2010 has now been released (I'm not an expert). SharePoint 2010 Foundation is roughly equivalent to WSS 3.0. SharePoint 2010 is 64 bit only. It looks like quite a nice step up from WSS 3 / MOSS 2007. Don't forget though that SPT 2007 is already 3 years old, so it's already well advanced down its support lifecycle.